# Setting RequestOptions CosmosDB Output binding on azure functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I am using an azure function to store data into a cosmosDB.

I am trying to implement this using an output binding

`[CosmosDB(databaseName: "ToDoItems", collectionName: "Items", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]out dynamic document`.

Is there a way I can set RequestOptions in the output binding above like you can when using the azure cosmosdb sdk as follow?

````
Document doc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(
        "something",
        {},
        new RequestOptions
        {
           AccessCondition = new AccessCondition {
             Condition = document.ETag,
             Type = AccessConditionType.IfMatch
           }
        }); ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can obtain the `DocumentClient` instance underneath and run the `UpsertDocumentAsync` yourself:

```
[CosmosDB(databaseName: "ToDoItems", 
    collectionName: "Items", 
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient client
```

Has the same beneficial effect, as the instance you get injected is the same that the binding maintains underneath across executions.

Comment: Does that also make use of the automatic retry mechanism that is in place when using output binding of the cosmosdb SDK?

Comment: Yes. The Cosmos DB output binding internally calls UpsertDocument (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Bindings/CosmosDBAsyncCollector.cs#L77), you get the same benefit, plus you can do more things with the DocumentClient instance if you need to (like execute queries). Official documentation of this is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient-c